# Is a C# generic dictionary of structs thread safe if it doesn't resize?

Tags: c#, multithreading

If I preload a dictionary with structs and guarantee never to add any more items to it, will it be thread-safe if I update items from a single thread and read them from another.

```
struct DataItem
{
    public double Price;
    public double Size;
}

class Test
{
    Dictionary<string, DataItem> items = new Dictionary<string,DataItem>(3);
    public Test ()
    {
        items["A"] = new DataItem(){Price=100, Size=1000};
        items["B"] = new DataItem(){Price=200, Size=2000};
        items["C"] = new DataItem(){Price=300, Size=3000};
    }
```

One thread would call this method

```
    public void UpdateItem()
    {
        DataItem newItem = new DataItem(){Price=400, Size=4000};
        items["A"] = newItem;    
    }
```

A different thread would be calling this method

```
    public DataItem GetItem(string key)
    {
        return items[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

it will  be thread safe if you have only one thread that read and update it which is the principle of thread safe  but in  your case no

For your future reference, the documentation is here :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

It says:

> A Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.

but if you want   you can take a look at

```
  ConcurentDictionary<key,Value>
```

introduced  with .Net 4.0  which is more suitable  for multithread scenario

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) says:

> A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified.

So it is not threadsafe to have both readers and writers operating simultaneously.

Comment: Yes I did read the documentation, I guess I was seeking clarification on the exact definition of "not modified".  Does this include changing the values as well as the keys?  To be safe I think I am going to use immutable objects rather than structs and store them in an array, with the dictionary just storing the indexes of the array elements. After the initialisation the dictionary will not be modified, instead the writer thread will just set references to new immutable objects within the array.

Comment: I think it's plausible that your usage would be fine and any races benign. But unless the documentation gives you clear indication that a specific type of modification is threadsafe then you can only assume that all modification could be unsafe. Studying extant implementations doesn't help. They are subject to change.

Answer (score 0):

It will be thread-safe as long as the structs can be read and written atomically — i.e. the actual size of the struct, including any padding, does not exceed one `IntPtr` or object reference (caveat: I am not sure whether `struct X { byte a; byte b; }` qualifies; I believe it depends on the jitter). The fact that you are using a dictionary is not relevant, the same issues arise with a struct-type variable shared between threads.

Comment: OK, so I am actually better using an immutable reference type rather than a struct.

Comment: Yes (you may also want to use [immutable collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385366.aspx)). Structs are generally best reserved for special uses — interop, wrappers around references etc.

Comment: The documentation contradicts you

Comment: @DavidHeffernan MSDN says "A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified." This leaves unclear whether changing the value associated with an already existing key counts as a modification. Reflector shows that updating a value will increment the dictionary's version, invalidating any iterators, but will not change anything else about the dictionary.

Comment: That's just one implementation